# firebase auth doesn't work in phones browsers and I make popup and redirct allowed

Tags: javascript, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, mobile-browser

I use firebase for auth,and it works in desktop browsers ,but it doesn't work on phone browser
this is code i use:

```js
function login() {
  const googleAuth = new GoogleAuthProvider();
  return signInWithPopup(auth, googleAuth).then(() =>getUserName(auth.currentUser.uid))
}
```

how can make it work in mobile browsers

Answer (score 2):

Signing in with a popup will not work reliably in mobile browsers. Use `signInWithRedirect` there instead.

From the Firebase documentation on [signing in with Google](https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/web/google-signin):

> The redirect method is preferred on mobile devices.